# How to bind the selection of CheckBox List to database WPF MVVM EF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, user-controls, checkboxlist

I am attempting to make a UserControl to create a CheckBoxList in WPF using MVVM.  Also, Entity Framework is being used to deploy the data.  Given the following:

WPF (UserControl)

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Sport}" 
                          Tag="{Binding SportsId}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Classes

```
public class Athlete
{
    public int AthleteId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sports> Sports { get; set; }

}

public class Sports {
    public int SportsId { get; set; }
    public string Sport { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get the UserControl to load the entire list of the Sports class and then select the ones that the Athlete can play?

Comment: please google for MVVM, learn some basics, try a solution and if you encounter a problem ask it here providing the details about the problem.

Comment: I have gone through the Google results that would seem relevant.  However, I cannot find any that shows binding to a database.  The ones I find show you how to create a list from an ObservableCollection and then get the results of the ones checked.  I have not been able to find anything that shows how to do a two way binding.

Comment: that is because binding the view directly to a db model, besides being too problematic, is considered an anti-pattern in MVVM as well as many other design patterns. You may find a way around it but is not recommended at all.

Comment: I'm not binding the view to the DB.  I am trying to create a UserControl that will take in 2 properties from the VM.  One being the complete list of available items (Sports) and one with a collection (sports the athlete can play).  Then I want the UserControl to check the boxes the athlete plays.  So if the athlete can play 2 of 5 sports, those 2 are already checked.  All the Google results show creating a list of boxes with a click event to build a list to return (One-way data). I need two-way data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue.  I was able to find it [here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/08/04/checkbox-list-in-wpf/).  It goes like this:

WPF UserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.CheckBoxList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="ThisCheckBoxList"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl x:Name="host"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ThisCheckBoxList, Path=ItemsSource}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:MyCheckBox x:Name="theCheckbox"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ElementName=ThisCheckBoxList, Path=DisplayPropertyPath}" 
                                          Unchecked="MyCheckBox_Checked"   
                                          Checked="MyCheckBox_Checked" 
                                          Tag="{Binding Path=.}">
                            <local:MyCheckBox.IsChecked >
                                <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" >
                                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                        <local:IsCheckedValueConverter />
                                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                    <Binding Path="."></Binding>
                                    <Binding ElementName="ThisCheckBoxList" Path="SelectedItems"></Binding>
                                    <Binding ElementName="ThisCheckBoxList" Path="DisplayPropertyPath"></Binding>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </local:MyCheckBox.IsChecked>
                        </local:MyCheckBox>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

WPF UserControl.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Eden
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CheckBoxList.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CheckBoxList : UserControl
    {
        public CheckBoxList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public object ItemsSource
        {
            get => GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(CheckBoxList),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args)));

        public IList SelectedItems
        {
            get => (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
        }



        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItems.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(CheckBoxList),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, SelectedChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when selected property changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        private static void SelectedChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged ncc)
            {
                ncc.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    CheckBoxList thiscontrol = (CheckBoxList)obj;
                    RebindAllCheckbox(thiscontrol.host);
                };
            }
        }

        private static void RebindAllCheckbox(DependencyObject de)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(de); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject dobj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(de, i);
                if (dobj is CheckBox cb)
                {
                    var bexpression = BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression(cb, MyCheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
                    if (bexpression != null) bexpression.UpdateTarget();
                }
                RebindAllCheckbox(dobj);
            }
        }



        public string DisplayPropertyPath
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(DisplayPropertyPathProperty);
            set => SetValue(DisplayPropertyPathProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayPropertyPath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayPropertyPathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayPropertyPath", typeof(string), typeof(CheckBoxList),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata("", (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args)));

        private PropertyInfo mDisplayPropertyPathPropertyInfo;

        private void MyCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SelectedItems == null)
                return;

            MyCheckBox chb = (MyCheckBox)sender;
            object related = chb.Tag;
            if (mDisplayPropertyPathPropertyInfo == null)
            {

                mDisplayPropertyPathPropertyInfo =
                    related.GetType().GetProperty(
                        DisplayPropertyPath, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            }

            object propertyValue;
            if (DisplayPropertyPath == ".")
                propertyValue = related;
            else
                propertyValue = mDisplayPropertyPathPropertyInfo.GetValue(related, null);

            if (chb.IsChecked == true)
            {
                if (!SelectedItems.Cast<object>()
                         .Any(o => propertyValue.Equals(
                                       DisplayPropertyPath == "." ? o : mDisplayPropertyPathPropertyInfo.GetValue(o, null))))
                {
                    SelectedItems.Add(related);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                object toDeselect = SelectedItems.Cast<object>()
                    .Where(o => propertyValue.Equals(DisplayPropertyPath == "." ? o : mDisplayPropertyPathPropertyInfo.GetValue(o, null)))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                if (toDeselect != null)
                {
                    SelectedItems.Remove(toDeselect);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
    {
        public string DisplayMemberPath
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty);
            set => SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayMemberPath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath",
             typeof(string),
             typeof(MyCheckBox),
             new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, (sender, args) =>
             {
                 MyCheckBox item = (MyCheckBox)sender;
                 Binding contentBinding = new Binding((string)args.NewValue);
                 item.SetBinding(ContentProperty, contentBinding);
             }));
    }
}
```

BaseMultiValueConverter

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Eden
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A base value converter that allows direct XAML usage
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of this value converter</typeparam>
    public abstract class BaseMultiValueConverter<T> : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
        where T : class, new()
    {

        #region Private Variables

        /// <summary>
        /// A single static instance of this value converter
        /// </summary>
        private static T Coverter = null;

        #endregion

        #region Markup Extension Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Provides a static instance of the value converter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceProvider">The service provider</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return Coverter ?? (Coverter = new T());
        }

        #endregion

        #region Value Converter Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// The method to convert on type to another
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <param name="targetType"></param>
        /// <param name="parameter"></param>
        /// <param name="culture"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public abstract object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);

        /// <summary>
        /// The method to convert a value back to it's source type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <param name="targetType"></param>
        /// <param name="parameter"></param>
        /// <param name="culture"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public abstract object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);

        #endregion
    }
}
```

IMultiValueConverter

```
using EcoDev.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Eden
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class IsCheckedValueConverter : BaseMultiValueConverter<IsCheckedValueConverter>
    {
        private PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }
        private Type ObjectType { get; set; }

        public override object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values[1] == null) return false; // IF I do not have no value for selected simply return false

            if (!(values[2] is string PropertyName)) return false;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName)) return false;
            if (!targetType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(bool))) throw new NotSupportedException("Can convert only to boolean");
            IEnumerable collection = values[1] as IEnumerable;
            object value = values[0];
            if (value.GetType() != ObjectType)
            {
                PropertyInfo = value.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                ObjectType = value.GetType();
            }
            foreach (var obj in collection)
            {
                if (PropertyName == ".")
                {
                    if (value.Equals(obj)) return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (PropertyInfo.GetValue(value, null).Equals(PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null))) return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }


        public override object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And then all you have to do in whatever window/page you want to use it in is use this code:

```
<local:CheckBoxList Height="Auto"
                    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"
                    DisplayPropertyPath="Text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is very broad and vague but I try to explain the best I can. You may need to read the whole thing at least twice. And also read [the external link](https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern/) **to the end of it** or at least carefully read the codes in it.

First look at the final solution:

```
public class AthleteVM : DependencyObject
{
    public int AthleteId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<SportSelectionVM> _sports = new ObservableCollection<SportSelectionVM>();
    public ObservableCollection<SportSelectionVM> Sports { get { return _sports; } }

}

public class SportSelectionVM : DependencyObject
{
    public int SportsId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private Model.Sport _model;
    public SportSelectionVM(Model.Sport model, bool isSelected)
    {
        _model = model;
        SportsId = model.Id;
        Name = model.Name;
        IsSelected = isSelected;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets IsSelected Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(AthleteVM), new PropertyMetadata(false, (d, e) =>
        {
            //  PropertyChangedCallback
            var vm = d as SportSelectionVM;
            var val = (bool)e.NewValue;
            AthleteDataService.UpdateModel(vm._model, val);//database changes here
        }));
}
```

XAML:

```
    <ListBox Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Sports}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" 
                      Tag="{Binding SportsId}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

DataContext of this view is an instance of `AthleteVM`. add all sports to `Sports` in `AthleteVM` and set `IsSelected` on those necessary.

see the constructor: `public SportSelectionVM(Model.Sport model, bool isSelected)`

similar strategy should be used to create an `AthleteVM` or to populate AthleteVM list in its parent.

### EF and UOW:

As we know here's the idea behind MVVM:

> [Model] <--- [VM] <--TwoWay Binding--> [View]

When EF is added to this pattern, it is usually recommended to follow UOW pattern as well.

Typically the UOW (UnitOfWork) is an object which is in charge of **one** database transaction (I don't mean SQLTransaction) and it is recommended to always create a UOW inside a `using` statement so that it would be disposed afterwards. Using this approach, you should expect to run into this question: how different UOWs interact with each others. which answer is: they don't.

Each UOW creates a lazy copy of the database and starts to modify it until you tell it to discard or save. If another UOW is created in the middle of this process, it doesn't contain any of the changes made to previous UOWs, unless the previous UOW is saved.

So you don't have to worry about *Model* and instead, you'll focus on the *DataService* to have something [like this](https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern/).

### Model<->VM

Considering all this information, *ViewModel* simply uses an instance of a *DataService* to fetch data from database and puts them in bindable properties and observable collections to maintain a *TwoWay Binding*.

But *VM* and *Model* do not have a *TwoWay* relationship, meaning that any change to *ViewModel* should be reflected on *Model* and then be saved in database **manually**.

My favourite solution is to take full advantage of `PropertyChangedCallback` feature of `DependencyProperty` to tell the *DataService* to reflect the change:

```
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(MyViewModel), 
            new PropertyMetadata(0, (d,e)=>
            {
                var vm = d as MyViewModel;
                var val = (int)e.NewValue;//check conditions here
                vm._model.MyProperty = val;//update model
                vm._dataService.Update(vm._model);//update database
            }));
```

in above sample, class `MyViewModel` has an instance of `_model` and `_dataService`.